# Сохранение данных при смене ориентации, фрагментов

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Господа, такой вопрос, как реализовать сохранение выбранного до смены ориентации фрагмента, и последующего его восстановления? Только вот вопрос получать int позиции? Или получать ID?

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle setFragment) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(setFragment);
        setFragment.putInt("position", position);
      }
      protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
      }
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
  Toolbar toolbar;
  ActionBar actionBar;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
      setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }

    setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);

    //First start (Inbox Fragment)
    setFragment(0);

  }


  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case android.R.id.home:
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle setFragment) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(setFragment);
    setFragment.putInt("position", position);

  }

  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
  }
  private void setupNavigationDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.bag:
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
              menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
              menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            setFragment(0);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
          case R.id.home:
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
              menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
              menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            setFragment(1);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
          case R.id.job:
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
              menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
              menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            setFragment(2);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
          case R.id.market:
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
              menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
              menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            setFragment(3);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
          case R.id.status:
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
              menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
              menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            setFragment(4);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
          case R.id.map:
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
              menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
              menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            setFragment(5);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

  public void setFragment(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    switch (position) {
      case 0:
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentBag fragmentBag = new FragmentBag();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentBag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
      case 1:
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentHome fragmentHome = new FragmentHome();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentHome);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
      case 2:
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentJob fragmentJob = new FragmentJob();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentJob);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
      case 3:
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentMarket fragmentMarket = new FragmentMarket();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentMarket);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
      case 4:
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentStatus fragmentStatus = new FragmentStatus();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentStatus);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
      case 5:
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentMap fragmentMap = new FragmentMap();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentMap);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно пытаться это делать ;) Активити сама помнит какой у нее был фрагмент до поворота экрана, и сама его восстановит! Вам нужно добавить проверку в методе `onCreate`, чтоб делать установку нулевого фрагмента только при первом запуске активити:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null)
   setFragment(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Так есть же замечательный триггер `savedInstenceState` в `onCreate()`. Если `savedInstenceState` равен `null`, то активити создается впервые и можно смело вызывать `setFragment(0)`. Иначе, активити сама восстановит фрагмент.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    setFragment(0);
}
```

Есть второй вариант. Можно проверять имеется ли во `FragmentManager` фрагмент с id `R.id.container`. Если есть, то ничего не делать, а если нет - `setFragment(0)`:

```
Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
if (f == null) {
    setFragment(0);
}
```

Comment: Мне бы ваши мозги)спасибо